# Display formula symbols in GUI static text

Tags: matlab, user-interface

is there any way I can display formula symbols in a static text on a gui?

[image]

Or is the only option to add a jpg?

Comment: Change your slash (`/`) to a backslash (`\ `) for one thing.

Comment: yep you're right but this doesn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Static text boxes](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uicontrol.html) don't support TeX/LateX formatting. You will need to use either the [`text`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/text.html) or [`annotation`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/annotation.html) functions (example [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/text-with-mathematical-expressions-using-latex.html)).